# How can I capture start/end tests events when writing Selenium IDE plugins

Tags: firefox-addon, selenium-ide

I am writing a Selenium IDE plugin which needs to perform actions when a test start/ends/fails. How can I intercept these events?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any provision of the same in IDE, but you can use JUnit and TestNG for the same. You need to export the test case in required format and add the method. I have done this may times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I want to write a plugin for the IDE, not a specific test..